# Reproducing a lollipop graph with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, lollipop

I want to create a lollipop graph something like given below:
[image]

So for I got the following:
[image]

using the following code

```
# Library
library(tidyverse)
 
# Create data
df1 <- 
  data.frame(
    x = c(2014, 2014, 2017, 2017, 2021, 2021)
  , y = c(1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1)
  )


df1

# plot
ggplot(data = df1, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = x, xend = x, y = 0, yend = y)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = 2014, xend = 2021, y = 0, yend = 0)) +
  geom_point(
      size   = 5
    , color  = "red"
    , fill   = alpha("orange", 0.3)
    , alpha  = 0.7
    , shape  = 21
    , stroke = 2
    ) +
  theme_void()
```

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible dataset for all of the data you want to include in the plot as a solution would be dependant on the initial data setup.

Comment: Thanks @Peter for your  comment. We can use any factitious data as given in my code.

Comment: On a sidenote: the example graph, probably a CV, uses pin*points* along a timescale to indicate the exact opposite (a time*span*), falsely suggesting equal durations at that. It also juxtaposes items of the same quality and series. Unless the graph has primarily decorative purpose, it might thus quite miss the point of a visualisation (to facilitate appraisal and interpretation of data). Which might be a particularly unfortunate choice for an application in the data science domain. My 2c ;-)

Comment: @I_O: Excellent point and a remarkable observation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possible approach which could be adapted to suit specific requirements...

You may need to adjust the parameters to suit your data and graphical device.

The balance of work done within the call to `ggplot` and the dataframe is fairly arbitrary; the setting of y and x coordinates for the various elements of the diagram could be set in the data frame.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggforce)
library(ggtext)

# Assumed data
df2 <- 
  data.frame(
    start = c(2014, 2017, 2018, 2021),
    qual = c("BSc", "MRes", "Phd", "DS" ),
    loc = paste("Uni", LETTERS[1:4])) |> 
  mutate(qual = factor(qual, levels = qual, ordered = TRUE),
         lab = paste0("**", qual, "**<br>", loc),
         dur = paste0(start, "\n-\n", lead(start)),
         dur = stringr::str_replace(dur, "NA", "now"))


ggplot(data = df2) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = -Inf, xend = Inf, y = 0, yend = 0)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = qual, xend = qual, y = 0, yend = rep(c(0.75, -0.75), 2))) +
  geom_point(aes(x = qual, y = 0), size = 3)+
  geom_circle(aes(x0 = 1:4, y0 = rep(c(1, -1), 2), r = 0.35),
              fill = "aquamarine4",
              colour = NA)+
  geom_richtext(aes(x = qual, y = rep(c(-0.5, 0.5), 2), label = lab),
            size = 6,
            family = "serif",
            colour = "aquamarine4",
            label.colour = NA)+
  geom_text(aes(x = qual, y = rep(c(1, -1), 2), label = dur),
            colour = "white",
            size = 6,
            family = "serif") +
  ylim(-1.5, 1.5) +
  theme_void() +
  coord_fixed()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>